# Ctypes send an array of structures

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have to realize a project between Python and C. One of the instructions is to use `ctypes`, so I need to call my C function from Python. The latter needs me to send it two integer variables and a structure array. But I can't get the declaration to work. I don't know how to make the declaration.

C:

```c
typedef struct    //Defini une structure qui a été envoyée par le code Python et qui contient uniquement les élements utiles
{
    int UID;
    float prix;
    float poids;
    int quantite;
    int nb_commande;
} reference;

int sac_dos_brute(int nb_produit, reference *tab, float masse) // Recupere le nombre de produits et un tableau de structures pour pouvoir gérrer l'expedition
{
    tri(tab, nb_produit);
    remplir_camion(tab,nb_produit,masse);
    return tab;
}
```

Python:

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('C:/..../workplease.dll')

class reference (Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('UID',c_int),
        ('prix',c_float),
        ('poids',c_float),
        ('quantite',c_int),
        ('nb_commande',c_int),
    ]

'''dll.sac_dos_brute.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, POINTER(reference)]
dll.sac_dos_brute(nb_produits, nb_camion, tab)'''

nb_produit=2
dll.sac_dos_brute.argtypes=[POINTER(reference)]
tab = [reference()]*2
tab[0].UID = 234
tab[0].prix= 12
tab[0].poids= 234
tab[0].quantite= 3
tab[0].nb_commande=1

tab[1].UID = 237
tab[1].prix= 15
tab[1].poids= 256
tab[1].quantite= 6
tab[1].nb_commande=2
    
dll.sac_dos_brute.argtype(c_int,c_int,c_, )
t = dll.sac_dos_brute(nb_produit,  byref(tab))
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried please, and your C function.

Comment: The function C                                                                                                                                                  int sac_dos_brute(int nb_produit, reference *tab, float masse) 
{
    tri(tab, nb_produit);
    remplir_camion(tab,nb_produit,masse);

    return tab;

}

Comment: Python:                                                                                                                                                                 
dll.sac_dos_brute.argtype(c_int,c_int,c_, )
t = dll.sac_dos_brute(nb_produit,  byref(tab))

Comment: Ok thanks, it's better if you edit your question with this code, for clarity.

Comment: @ThibaultNaud by editing the question, please (with formatting) :). And that is your C code. What we also need is, from the python side, what you've tried to call (not to check if you've tried. But because explanation are easier from what you tried. That being said, it wouldn't be a good idea from us to just give you the answer. Especially if my colleague Taha's is your teacher? Is he still the one teaching this?)

Comment: And how is defined the structure from the C side? That is the `struct reference` or `typedef struct {...} reference` ? For now (I've tried it yet, it doesn't seem awfully wrong.

Comment: @chrslg I'm sorry I didn't understand how the site worked, I created my account just before because Taha (that's my teacher) told us about it the other day and he's not available this week to help me. You were also at the utt? It's a small world

Comment: I added my structure in C, I know that my C code works because I did tests by initializing directly in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `.argtypes` and `.restype` exactly match the C function in type and order of parameters.

Constructing a `ctypes` array is done by `(type * size)(item, item, ...)`.

Below is C DLL code to print what was received for debugging:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct {
    int UID;
    float prix;
    float poids;
    int quantite;
    int nb_commande;
} reference;

API int sac_dos_brute(int nb_produit, reference *tab, float masse) {
    printf("masse = %f\n", masse);
    for(int i = 0; i < nb_produit; ++i)
        printf("tab[%d] = %d, %f ,%f, %d, %d\n",
            i, tab[i].UID, tab[i].prix, tab[i].poids, tab[i].quantite, tab[i].nb_commande);
    return 123;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Reference(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (('UID', ct.c_int),
                ('prix', ct.c_float),
                ('poids', ct.c_float),
                ('quantite', ct.c_int),
                ('nb_commande', ct.c_int))

    # Tell class how to display itself
    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'Reference(UID={self.UID}, prix={self.prix}, poids={self.poids}, '
                f'quantite={self.quantite}, nb_commande={self.nb_commande})')

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
# Make sure argument types and restype match the C function in type and order
dll.sac_dos_brute.argtypes = ct.c_int, ct.POINTER(Reference), ct.c_float
dll.sac_dos_brute.restype = ct.c_int

# Efficient way to create an array of two Reference types.
tab = (Reference * 2)(Reference(234, 12, 234, 3, 1),
                      Reference(237, 15, 256, 6, 2))

# Test __repr__
for t in tab:
    print(t)

# Test the function
print(dll.sac_dos_brute(len(tab), tab, 1.25))
```

Output:

```
Reference(UID=234, prix=12.0, poids=234.0, quantite=3, nb_commande=1)
Reference(UID=237, prix=15.0, poids=256.0, quantite=6, nb_commande=2)
masse = 1.250000
tab[0] = 234, 12.000000 ,234.000000, 3, 1
tab[1] = 237, 15.000000 ,256.000000, 6, 2
123
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you were creating a `list[reference]` instead of `Array[reference]` which translates to `tab = (reference * 2)()`. Let's see if this works:

```
import ctypes as c

def sac_dos_brute(nb_produit: int, reference: c.Array[reference], masse: float) -> None:
    dll = c.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:/..../workplease.dll')
    dll.sac_dos_brute(c.c_int(nb_produit), c.byref(reference), c.c_float(masse))

nb_produit: int = 2
tab = (reference * 2)()
tab[0].UID = 234
tab[0].nom = b'Iphone'
tab[0].prix = 12.0
tab[0].poids = 234.0
tab[0].categorie = b'Telephone'
tab[0].marque = b'Apple'
tab[0].annee = 2020
tab[0].quantite = 3
tab[0].nb_commande = 1
tab[0].avis = 5
tab[1].UID = 237
tab[1].nom = b'Ipad'
tab[1].prix = 15.0
tab[1].poids = 256.0
tab[1].categorie = b'Tablette'
tab[1].marque = b'Apple'
tab[1].annee = 2022
tab[1].quantite = 6
tab[1].nb_commande = 2
tab[1].avis = 4
masse: float = 0.0

sac_dos_brute(nb_produit, tab, masse)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CreepyRaccoon , I tested your code and I have a new little problem.                                                      class reference (Structure):

NameError: name 'Structure' is not defined

Comment: I think is because of `import ctypes as c`, you have to change it to `c.Structure`. Bear in mind that imports like `from ctypes import *` are not recommended. Sorry, I forgot to add these extra changes to code for "the sake of easiness".

Comment: Thanks, I modified the types as well to make it work                                                                class reference (c.Structure):
  _fields_ =[
      ('UID',c.c_int),
      ('prix',c.c_float),
      ('poids',c.c_float),
      ('quantite',c.c_int),
      ('nb_commande',c.c_int),
  ]

Comment: . Now my mistake is here.                                                                                                             def sac_dos_brute(nb_produit: int, reference: c.Array[reference], masse: float) -> None:

TypeError: '_ctypes.PyCArrayType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I don't have this error, are you sure you are passing an array instance?? i.e.: `tab = (reference * 2)()`. This error ocurrs when passing just `tab = reference * 2`.

Comment: Try also removing the explicit types, because it could give you problems depending on your Python version, I use v3.11.

Answer (score 0):

Since C profile is

```c
int sac_dos_brute(int nb_produit, reference *tab, float masse) ;
```

argtypes should be

```py
dll.sac_dos_brute.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(reference), c_float]
```

That one, I am sure you've already tried, and is false in your code just because you are in the process of trying many things. But just to be sure...

Then, the way you are creating the array is not correct.

```py
[reference()]*2
```

is a call to `reference()`, which creates one structure, repeated in an array. You don't want a python list containing several structures (even less if it is several times the same one). You wan't an array to a `reference`, and to be more accurate, an array to 2 of them

So, it should be

```py
tab = (reference * 2)()
```

(I see that you've already been told that while I was away)

But then, argument passing is way easier. You don't need `byref` here (`byref` is when you are passing a structure, for example, but want the C code to receive a pointer to it. You don't want that, since what you have, tab, is already an array. It will be passed as a pointer to function)

So, simply call

```py
dll.sac_dos_brute(nb_produit, tab, masse)
```

So altogether (without any change to your C code, assuming that it reflects the change you've made since in your python code)

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('C:/..../workplease.dll')

class reference (Structure):
  _fields_ =[
      ('UID',c_int),
      ('prix',c_float),
      ('poids',c_float),
      ('quantite',c_int),
      ('nb_commande',c_int),
  ]

dll.sac_dos_brute.argtypes=[c_int, POINTER(reference), c_float]


nb_produit=2
tab = (reference*nb_produit)()

tab[0].UID = 234
tab[0].prix= 12
tab[0].poids= 234
tab[0].quantite= 3
tab[0].nb_commande=1

tab[1].UID = 237
tab[1].prix= 15
tab[1].poids= 256
tab[1].quantite= 6
tab[1].nb_commande=2

masse=3.14 # Just something I've chosen to fill the holes
    
t = dll.sac_dos_brute(nb_produit, tab, masse)
```

And of course, from there, you can't put back the fields you've removed, as long as you put them back in both (C and python) structure, and in the same order.
For what I saw, you were using them correctly (using b-string, as you should).